# Module '"react-router-dom"' has no exported member 'match'

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom

Hi i'm currently upgrading `react-router-dom` from `5.2.0` to `6.3.0` for my react typescript application. while converting the application I'm getting this error `Module '"react-router-dom"' has no exported member 'match'.`

here you can find the below code.

```
import { match } from 'react-router-dom';

export interface ContentTypeIdParams {
  contentTypeId: string;
}

export interface ContentTypeBreadcrumbProps {
  match: match<ContentTypeIdParams>;
}
```

I'm facing this error in my interface.

my route path

```
<Route
        path={`${RoutesEnum.RELEVANCE_TESTING_VERSIONS_COMPARISON_TEST_CASE}*`}
        element={({ match: { params } }) => (
          <Redirect
            to={getUrlWithParams(
              RoutesEnum.RELEVANCE_TESTING_VERSIONS_COMPARISON,
              params
            )}
          />
```

I searched a lot about this error but couldn't find any answers or questions.
if anyone knows about this kindly answer this.

Comment: There are no route props in RRDv6. Are you just trying to get the route path params?

Comment: yes, i'm trying to get the router path param

Comment: are they removed RouteComponentProps from react-router as well??

Comment: Yes, I believe so as there are no longer any route props. Is it the [`Params`](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/lib/router.ts#L79-L84) type you need? RRDv6 has a lot of breaking changes from v5. Routing/navigation implementation was really changed.

Comment: yes, I need to check the param type in the route path params. and I need to use match. can you check the question i have updated my route path. can you check and confirm me is it possible to send the match. i'm getting error in the params aswell

Comment: The `Route` component's `element` prop takes ***only*** a `ReactNode` type, i.e. JSX. The function is invalid. Perhaps it would be best to share a complete example for what you are trying to accomplish. Sometimes it is helpful to share a complete and working RRDv5 example, and then the complete v6 version so we can see where things go sideways for you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are just wanting to "sniff" the route's `params` object to pass to a path generating utility function. The `Route` component takes only a `ReactNode`, a.k.a. JSX on the single `element` prop. There are also no longer any route props, replaced by React hooks.

Create a component that accesses the route path params via the `useParams` hook and renders a declarative redirect.

*I'm not sure what `RoutesEnum.RELEVANCE_TESTING_VERSIONS_COMPARISON` is so passing it in as a prop to `Redirect`. It's not something being mapped over then it might be something that is just imported and used, and in this case the `paramArg` isn't necessary.*

Example:

```
import { Navigate, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

const Redirect = ({ paramArg }) => {
  const params = useParams();

  return <Navigate to={getUrlWithParams(paramArg, params)} replace />;
};

export default Redirect;
```

...

```
import Redirect from '../path/to/Redirect';

...

<Route
  path={`${RoutesEnum.RELEVANCE_TESTING_VERSIONS_COMPARISON_TEST_CASE}*`}
  element={<Redirect paramArg={RoutesEnum.RELEVANCE_TESTING_VERSIONS_COMPARISON} />}
/>
```